# Table joined with different tables with one common column in the foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with JPA when I try to join a table on 2 other tables using one common column.

I have a table project_user mapped to the class ProjectUser with the columns

- project_id (composite foreign key to the table project)
  _ user_account_token (composite foreign key to the table domain_user)
- domain_id (composite foreign key to the table project AND domain_user)

A table project with primary key

- project_id
- domain_id

And a table domain_user with primary key

- user_account_token_id
- domain_id

Here is the code :

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "project_users", schema = "public")
@IdClass(ProjectUserId.class)
public class ProjectUser implements Persistable<ProjectUserId> {
    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", referencedColumnName = "domain_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Project project;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", referencedColumnName = "domain_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_token", referencedColumnName = "user_account_token_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private DomainUser domainUser;
}
```

This does not seem to work, the error I get is :

> could not insert: [commodel.ProjectUser]; SQL [insert into public.project_users (last_access, ref_project_user_role_id, domain_id, user_account_token, project_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [model.ProjectUser]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling on this - it has to do with the data you are trying to insert - for me it was attempting to insert a String that was longer than the size set in the Hibernate annotations. *In debugging*, you can follow the *cause of the Exception* to find the root cause.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Actually, it had to do with the number of arguments passed. It is 6 instead of 5. I think it is because it tries to insert twice the domain_id because it belongs to both of the JoinColumns